# Server.MapPath behaves differently with IIS Server and ASP.Net Development Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Why does `Server.MapPath("~")` return different results with IIS Express and ASP.Net Development server?

When I run my application with ASP.Net Development Server, my path returns like `"D:\\MyProject\\Web\\WWWRoot\\ISuite5"` but when i run using IIS Express , path comes as `"D:\\MyProject\\Web\\WWWRoot\\ISuite5\\"`. There is a difference of `"\\"` between both. I am not able to figure out the reason behind it or how to resolve it so that IIS Server also returns the same result as ASP.Net Development Server.

Comment: This should be no problem if you use Path.Combine

Comment: Try Server.MapPath("~/"), makes more sense.

Comment: The result is same even when i use Server.MapPath("~/").

Comment: Use Path.Combine so you you won't worry about the slashes

Comment: Actually i am using Path.GetDirectoryName . So, in this case when i am using Development Server Path.GetDirectoryName returns "D:\\MyProject\\Web\\WWWRoot. But, when i use IIS Express Path.GetDirectoryName returns D:\\MyProject\\Web\\WWWRoot\\ISuite5